# Confidence intervals for predictions from linear discriminant analysis

Tags: r, confidence-interval, prediction, discriminant-analysis

I wan't to draw 95% prediction area of an LDA model.

I can draw the prediciton area, however with no information on the confidence.

```
# train model ----
mdl1 <- MASS::lda(y~ x1+ x2,data=traindata)
summary(mdl1)

# partition matrix
klaR::partimat(y~  x1+ x2, data=traindata, method="lda",prec=250,
               image.colors=c("pink","lightgreen","lightblue"),
               na.correct=NA, col.wrong=NA,
               gs=NA,
               col.mean=NA,
               main="Main title")
```

I would like to get something like in this article: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0048969712016191

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to calculate confident interval is to use **bootstrap** : repeat your model several times (exemple 100 times) on a random subsample of your dataset (randomly select 90% of your dataset each time).

Instead of having one result, you will have 100 results (similar results, but with a slight difference) and you can use these results to build your confident interval (order your results and take quantile 5% and 95%)

Comment: Quite trivial, still didn't think upon it. Thanks!